# the value from mqtt is not sending

Tags: python, kivy, mqtt, iot

im running a smart parking in proteus and building an application in kivy.so the problem is when i run the code it just displays the unknown.img, like slot1 unknown,slot2 unkown, slot3 unknown

how can i establish the connection.
without the kivy the connection was fine and it shows the result

```
import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivy.uix.label import Label

broker_address = "broker.hivemq.com"  # Replace with your MQTT broker address
slot1_topic = "slot1"
slot2_topic = "slot2"
slot3_topic = "slot3"


slot_statuses = {
    slot1_topic: "Unknown",
    slot2_topic: "Unknown",
    slot3_topic: "Unknown"
}

slot_labels = {}
slot_images = {}

def on_connect(client, userdata, flags, rc):
    print("Connected with result code " + str(rc))
    if rc == 0:
        print("Connected to MQTT broker")
    else:
        print("Connection failed. Return code: " + str(rc))

    # Subscribe to parking slot topics
    client.subscribe(slot1_topic)
    client.subscribe(slot2_topic)
    client.subscribe(slot3_topic)


def on_message(client, userdata, msg):
    topic = msg.topic
    status = msg.payload.decode()
    slot_statuses[topic] = status
    update_gui()



def update_gui():
    for slot, status in slot_statuses.items():
        label = slot_labels[slot]
        image = slot_images[slot]
        if status == "1":
            label.text = f"{slot} Parked"
            image.source = f"{slot}car_parked.png"
        elif status == "0":
            label.text = f"{slot} Free"
            image.source = f"{slot}car_free.png"
        else:
            label.text = f"{slot} Unknown"
            image.source = "unknown.jpg"

client = mqtt.Client()


client.on_connect = on_connect
client.on_message = on_message

client.connect(broker_address, 1883, 60)


class ParkingApp(App):
    def build(self):
        layout = BoxLayout(orientation='vertical')
        for slot in slot_statuses:
            label = Label(text=f"{slot} Unknown", halign='center', valign='middle')
            image = Image(source="unknown.jpg")  # Default image for unknown state
            layout.add_widget(label)
            layout.add_widget(image)
            slot_labels[slot] = label
            slot_images[slot] = image
        return layout


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = ParkingApp()
    app.run()
```

the values from mqtt (0,1) should be passes to the code above

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with mqtt, but taking a quick look at the documentation, the "action" in mqtt happens in the network loop.  Kivy is also loop based.  You need to integrate the two loops.

Looking at: https://eclipse.dev/paho/index.php?page=clients/python/docs/index.php#network-loop

I would suggest using the kivy clock to schedule a call to loop() at the longest regular interval your app can support.  I would also set the timeout in loop to be short (0.25, or shorter).  Leaving the timeout too long will cause the gui to lock up while waiting for a time out.